# Xcode project template and Swift Package dependencies

Tags: swift, xcode, templates, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to create a project template for Xcode from various sources and I wondered if it was possible to automatically add some Swift Package Manager dependencies ? I know it can be done with Cocoapod, but I didn't find anything regarding SPM.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello Khal.. I am looking for the same. Any update?

Answer (score -1):

Hope make sense

```
 $ mkdir YourKit
 $ cd YourKit
 $ swift package init
```

Comment: sorry, it's not. I want to create a project template so that I can choose this template when creating a new project (https://blog.showoff.ie/xcode-custom-project-templates-advance-5ac92a0f4672), but thanks ;-)